# How can I make this code by oop

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

I've a button called `profile_btn`

I want to make this code by OOP .

```
profile_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,profile_btnClickHandler);
function profile_btnClickHandler(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    //The actual code to jump to a specific frame
    this.gotoAndPlay('play');
}
```

Also, how can I include three classes to a specific frame by actionscript3 that aren't related  to any object

Comment: Line 7 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: profile_btn.

Comment: profile_btn should be an instance name of a button on stage.....for the error u just mentioned.

Comment: The instance name 'profile_btn' is declared on an object of type profile_btn but there is a conflicting use of the instance name 'profile_btn ' on an object of type flash.display.SimpleButton.

Comment: it's a name of btn in the library and the class linked to this button i just want to create the button dynamically and go to the frame i want

Comment: "adding 3 classes to a frame" doesn't make sense.Also, I think it would be better if you ask new questions in new threads rather than editing the old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following can be used if you have a class (the name you specified in linkage) profile_btn.

```
var myButton:profile_btn =new profile_btn()
```

If your want to add it to stage use:

```
stage.addChild(myButton);
```

So you code might look as

```
var myButton:profile_btn =new profile_btn()

stage.addChild(myButton);

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,profile_btnClickHandler);

function profile_btnClickHandler(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    //The actual code to jump to a specific frame
    this.gotoAndPlay('play');
}
```

Comment: i get this error Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/get currentScene()
 at fl.motion::AnimatorBase/handleEnterFrame()
 at btn_profile()

Comment: and how to  include this  class in a specific frame by actionscript3

Comment: I don't get it, all you have to do is set the button's "class" value to profile_btn. Rest the code will automatically reference & add it. Ohh make sure you check "export in frame 1" & "export in AS".

Comment: I copy this code without editing and it's work without errors but the btn doesn't appear ,

Comment: and if i want to make it appear in a specific frame how can i make it , note the button in the library i didn't put it in the stage as i use addChild method

Comment: the button will appear right at the top left corner of stage. Also for specific frames, all you need to do is select the required frame & write code to the as panel of that frame.

Comment: select a frame, open the as panel, call the class like " var ObjectName: ClassName = new ClassName(); "